# hotkey to connect MacBook Air as second monitor

Tags: macbook, external-display, imac

The hotkey (cmd + F2) works on the keyboard of iMac to connect iMac as second monitor for MacBook Air, but not otherwise round, on the keyboard for MacBook Air this hotkey does not work. Does anybody know how can I get MacBook Air as second monitor for iMac?

Comment: see https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/use-your-mac-as-a-display-mchl7d43ecb2/mac -- I've not had time to try it yet, but from the title it probably provides a more recent, working answer (?)

Answer (score 0):

## You can't.

Only a small subset of iMacs were ever made which could use Target Display Mode; no other Mac model is capable.

See Apple KB - [Use your iMac as a display with Target Display Mode](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT204592)

Comment: hm, I looked your link. my iMac has this possibility to be connected as second Monitor. and cmd F2 works on it. But it does not work on MacBook Air. and I need on it

Comment: "it does not work on MacBook Air"... Correct, it does not work on MacBook Air, or any Mac except the ones listed on that KB page. Salient part of my answer edited.

Comment: ah, yes, thanks. my MacBook Air is not listed there :(